# Call CPP Function from RTSP-Media-Factory.c

Tags: gstreamer

I have CPP Function. I need to call this function from `rtsp_media_factory.c` file in Gstreamer rtspServer.

How can I call this function?

I have a function pointer

```
GstElement* CreatePipeline(GstRTSPMediaFactory *factory)
```

in `rtsp_media_factory.c`.

I need to assign a CPP class function to above function pointer.

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you describe some more detailed what is the problem, what do you want to achieve and what did you tried for this?

Comment: I just modified the question, check it once

Comment: Possibly if you specify **Gstreamer** version (i. e. where you got this source from) and your task, it will be simpler to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is really function pointer, you can assign to it only `static` class member because other members also contains `this` in signature. But, as I understand, you can assign to it any function (not class member).